# Pandas: How to relabel the index of rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Currently I have:
[image]

I would like the row indices on the left of product_id to start from 0 in ascending order. Is that possible?

Comment: `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `sort_index()` method:

```
df=df.sort_index()
```

**if your index doesn't start with 0 after sorting then:**

Use `reset_index()`:

```
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I think `reset_index(drop=True)` does the `drop` automatically

Comment: Thnx for the suggestion @tdy  **:)**

Answer (score 2):

you can use 'inplace' argument.

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace= True)
```